# bind-attr with conditional not working as expected in handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js

I put together a test fiddle to get the basics for a project I am working on. Unfortunately, I couldn't even get the basic functionality to work as I expected. Here is my fiddle fail http://jsfiddle.net/3oLa40mw/1/

jQuery 2.1.0
Handlebars 2.0.0

Html:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id='testTemplate'>
    <div {{bind-attr class="someBool:foo:bar"}}>
        {{firstName}} {{lastName}} {{someBool}}
    </div>
</script>
<div id='stuff'></div>
```

Script

```
var model = 
    {firstName: 'bob', lastName: 'mcbob', someBool: true, trueVal: 'y', falseVal: 'yy'};

var template = Handlebars.compile($("#testTemplate").html());
var html = template(model);
console.log(html);
$('#stuff').html(html);
```

The output is a div with no class attribute. No foo. No bar.

I expected `class="foo"` based on what I had seen in various tutorials. What did I miss?

My real end goal is something like:

```
    <div {{bind-attr class="someBool:some-{{name}}:someother-{{name}}"}}>
        {{firstName}} {{lastName}} {{someBool}}
    </div>
```

or

```
    <div {{bind-attr class="some-{{name}} someBool:someother"}}>
        {{firstName}} {{lastName}} {{someBool}}
    </div>
```

I can generate the css to work for either case. If I can get handlebars to spit out what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`bind-attr` is an Ember helper](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-class-names/), it's not available in Handlebars by default.

Comment: Well, that sucks. I am using backbone. I will refine the workarounds I have used so far. I think I may try Ember for my next project. Tyvm for the response.